# Pushing forward the canonical sheaf to a non-normal variety.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand the following (which for context, comes from the proof of 9.3.46 in Lazarsfeld's "Positivity II").

In the proof, we start with a reduced effective divisor $D$ on a smooth variety $X$, and we find that for some resolution of singularities $\nu: D' \to D $ of $D$, we have $\nu_* \mathcal{O}_{D'}(K_{D'}) = \omega_D$ where $\omega_D$ is the dualizing sheaf of $D$. It is then claimed that this implies that $D$ is normal, since otherwise it is singular in codimension 1.

In particular, we can factor $\nu$ through the normalization $D' \to \tilde{D} \stackrel{n}\to D$ of $D$. I'm guessing since the singular locus contains a Weil divisor, the pushforward of the canonical sheaf picks up some kind of discrepancy, but I am having a hard time making this rigorous.

How can we see that the pushforward of $\mathcal{O}_{D'}(K_{D'})$ is not the canonical sheaf of $D$?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use the following preliminary result.

Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is a finite morphism of reduced noetherian schemes and let $F$ be a coherent
sheaf on $X$. Suppose that $F$ is a line bundle on an open dense subscheme of $X$. Suppose that $f_*(F)$ is locally free of rank one. Consider the
adjunction morphism $f^*f_*(F)\to F$. This map is surjective because $f$ is affine.
I claim that it is also injective and so an isomorphism.

To show this, we may by construction
suppose that $f_*(F)$ is the trivial line bundle (replace $Y$ by a suitable open subscheme)
and then we obtain a surjection $a:{\cal O}_X\to F$. There is an open dense subscheme
where $F$ is a line bundle (by assumption) so ${\rm ker}(a)$ is $0$ over an open dense subscheme.
But ${\rm ker}(a)$ is a sheaf of ideals and so it defines a closed subscheme of $X$.
This closed subscheme is all of $X$ by the above, so ${\rm ker}(a)=0$, proving the claim.

Now consider the factorisation $D'\to X\to Y=D$, where $f:X\to Y=D$ is the normalisation map.
Let $g:D'\to X$ be the map in the factorisation. By your assumptions, the sheaf
$F=g_*({\cal O}(K_{D'}))$ satisfies the hypothesies of the claim
and so the map
$$
f^*f_*(F)\to F
$$
is an isomorphism. In particular, for every point $P\in D$, there is an open
neighbourhood $U_P$ of $P$, such that $f_*(F)$ is
free of rank one over $U_P$ and $F$ is free of rank one on
$f^{-1}(U_P)$. But then the restriction of $f$ to $U_P$ is flat of degree one and so an isomorphism. Since $P$ was arbitrary, this forces the normalisation map to be an isomorphism.